# Connect button not available in Firefox OS 1.1 simulator

Tags: debugging, simulator, firefox-os

I'm following this guide to debug a Firefox OS packaged app on the Firefox 1.1 simulator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_1.1_Simulator

I can run the web app in the simulator. But I have found no way to connect the debugging tools to the simulator, the "connect" button does not even appear. I'm using Firefox 25 in OSX 10.10.1

How can I debug the app that is running in the simulator?

Comment: What version of Firefox OS do you have on the phone and I assume you have remote debugging enabled? If you open a terminal and enter adb devices, does the phone show?

Comment: I'm not using a device, just the simulator.

Comment: Can you try the sample app? Download the https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App and unzip it. Use the add directory to point to the manifest.webapp, then refresh and the connect button should then work.

Comment: I have just tried the sample app from github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App and the "Connect" button does not appear either. I have also tried with Firefox on Windows 7 with the same result.

Comment: I just tried with ubuntu and it worked for me with Firefox 25. Have you tried using the latest Firefox with WebIDE?

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu and it does not display the "connect" button either. I'm looking to use the Firefox 1.1 simulator. WebIDE is for newer versions AFAIK

Comment: can you post the build number you are using for Firefox?

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1157792

Comment: I have successfully connected to the simulator once, using a combination of an older Firefox version and older Simulator add-on.